# I want to disable all keyboard event on full screen video player

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming

I am working on an HLS player. I implemented a chat module on a live player.
When I write some message. I can not write it because when Press space button of the keyboard player is stopped and not space added to the message.
I want to disable all keyboard event when the player in full-screen mode.
I am using HLS player for live channel.

Comment: how does your chat window work? how are you putting both the video and chat on the full screen? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript onkeydown.

Sample :
For disabling the key :

```
function keyDisable()
{
 document.onkeydown = function (e)  {
  return false;
 }
}
keyDisable();
```

For enabling the key

```
function keyEnable()
{
 document.onkeydown = function (e)  {
  return true;
 }
}
keyEnable()
```

Hope this will solve your problem